# Issue with deploying Kubeflow pipeline

Tags: kubernetes, pipeline, minikube, kubeflow, mlops

I am trying to follow this tutorial https://www.kubeflow.org/docs/components/pipelines/v1/installation/standalone-deployment/ on deploying kubeflow pipelines (i use minikube) but when the pods starts running, there is always a crashbackloop or some other error for the ml-pipeline server pod. How to fix that? I started minikube using docker engine.[image]